# Angular2: Cannot find name 'Promise' after having installed global dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, npm

I'm building an app using angular 2 and nodejs and I've installed the necessary dependencies from the package.json already. Inside of the package.json, there is a postinstall command to install the dependencies in typings.json. I was initially trying to install the es6-shim using:

```
"ambientDependencies": {
  "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
}
```

but running this returned the error:

`npm ERR! Failed at the support-dashboard@1.0.0 typings script 'typings "install"'.`

I then saw on quickstart guide for Angular that they have the following in their typings.json file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

so I installed those dependencies since the site says:

> We identified three typings file in the QuickStart, the d.ts files for
>   core-js that brings ES2015/ES6 capabilities to our ES5 browsers

For some reason though, when I start the server, I'm still getting the error that Promise can't be found. My company gets packages from the Node repositories we have on our servers so I think that maybe the github link that has been provided for the es6 shim might not work possibly, but I'm not sure.

**Is there something that has to be configured differently in order to get "Promise" to be recognized?**

### EDIT:

**Command prompt log from running `npm start`:**

```
bash-3.1$ npm start

> support-dashboard@1.0.0 start c:\MEAN_project
> concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "node server.js"

[1] Magic happens on port 8080
[0]
[0] > support-dashboard@1.0.0 tsc:w c:\MEAN_project
[0] > tsc -w
[0]
[0] node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(78,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(38,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(92,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(151,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(23,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(25,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(12,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(59,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(100,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(105,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(106,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(71,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(75,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(85,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[0] 8:52:59 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might not lie in your node.js setup, but in the version of your browser.

A Promise is [a construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in the new ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard. Is it possible that you are using an old browser. Because new Browsers should [recognize it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: Well, I'm getting the error: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.` before I even go to the site on localhost so I think the app itself is unable to find Promise

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 okay, I could not determine the error message from the post above. It would be a good addition to your post.

Comment: I just added the command prompt log of what appears when I run `npm start`